# Complex validation in service layer - how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best approach to write validation in service layer and pass error to controller? I have found that tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

In this tutorial we pass ModelState to own class called ModelStateWrapper and in service method we pass error to ModelStateWrapper. What do you think about this solution?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you linked is decent.

Basically what's happening is you want to decouple your service layer from your controllers.

So in order to do that you cannot use ModelState.  So in this tutorial they create an abstraction around the ModelState and use that instead.

Then in your controller's constructor you would just pass the populated `ModelStateWrapper` like in the tutorial

```
_service = new ProductService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), new ProductRepository());
```

I think this is a fine way to do it, another way to do it would just use something like a `Dictionary<string,string>` for your errors (instead of creating another type and wrapper), and have a utility method somewhere in a base controller or something that would convert this to your `ModelState`.

Advantage to using just a dictionary is everyone knows what it is, testing it is trivial, and you don't have to keep jumping back to your wrapper class to see how to use it properly, less abstractions ect.

I think either solution is fine.